# PPTP tunnel only wrapping TCP Traffic

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2008-r2, pptp

I am having difficulty configuring a PPTP VPN using Windows Server 2008 R2 to allow more then just TCP traffic.  Connection and authentication work perfectly, but applications that require other protocol suites don't work correctly (Games, Bonjour, NetBIOS, etc).

I've opened the two ports (47, 1723) to allow PPTP traffic & am I'm using RRAS. How can I get this to work?

Comment: <<Question bump>>